# What process do i take to understand an existing system for a very large hospital for example?

Tags: analysis, data-analysis

I've been asked to study and document the existing system for a tertiary hospital. The hospital consist of administrative (Accounts, Admin, Engineering,...) and clinic units (Pharmacy, The process by which a patient gets in and out of the hospital,...).

I would need to understand how data flows in and out and the business process.

It's a large hospital. How do i systematically analysis and document this system?

While i have this task, i have a generic system that can be implemented for the hospital and would like to tailor the system to their needs from my findings.

I need a plan in other to make this process a success. Can someone help me with a guide please?

Edit #1:

I found this helpful link

[How To Define and Outline Your Business Process Workflow](http://info.docuvantage.com/blog/bid/22422/How-To-Define-and-Outline-Your-Business-Process-Workflow)

Edit #2:

I have come up with a few question i think is necessary to start with. Please contribute to them and challenge them please.

- What function are peformed by your department?
- What Information comes into your department?
- What Information do you send out from you department?
- How do you use each information that comes in?
- What do you do with them?
- How do they flow?
- How the information that leaves the department are generated or gotten?
- How does each of this information flow?
- What information do you generate?
- What do you do with these information generated?

Comment: That questions sounds to me like "how to build a supertanker". Do you really think you can find a useful answer to a question like this here on SO?

Comment: Brown: Please do you know where i could read up some information? I tried search but have not found anything. I still look on google though.

Comment: Those questions might be the correct ones you want to get answered throughout the process. But you will get remarkably better results if you use and understand the vocabulary of the ones you are going to interview. So listen and and learn from them. I suspect "flow of information" is not a common verb in the domain of a hospital. And yes, the link you found seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this will really help you, but you could make yourself familiar with a methodoly like [BPMN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Notation) or [use case modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case).

EDIT: the name for the game you are going to start is [requirements analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis). Perhaps it is sufficient for you to go along the lines of that Wikipedia article, at least, it might be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

This tools are great, but i would love to have information that provides me with guides or advise on how to start or manage analysis process. Your advise above suggest tools and not how.

Comment: Good Suggestion. I found a link that i added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw mind maps bit by bit when understanding unclear requirements. It may be helpful to you.

Comment: My pleasure. I guess the hospital has existing documents explaining their work flow. Not sure whether they'd like to share them with you though.

Comment: They don't have documents like that. I was thinking of collecting forms from each department and document what does forms are for and how it moves around the hospital.

Comment: It makes the task more challenging. Good luck!